Change the double integral from cartresian to polar cordinates
I have to solve this following integral,
$$\int_0^{\rm A} \int_{\sqrt{R_g^2 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}+r_0} \arcsin{\left(\frac{R_{\rm g}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)} {\rm d}y {\rm d}x$$
Here ${\rm A}$, $R_{\rm g}$, $r_0$, and $R$ are positive constants. This integral cannot be solved in cartesian coordinates, So I am trying to first convert it to polar and then see what comes out. I am trying to verify my answer through numerical solution, but I am making some mistake.
It would be helpful if some can guide me. Also, I think I am messing up the limits of integration
EDIT:
Using $x=r\cos\theta$, and $y = r\sin\theta$, limits of integration change from $y = \sqrt{R_g^2 - x^2}$ to $r = R$, and $y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}+r_0$ to $r = r_0\sin\theta + \sqrt{(r_0\sin\theta)^2 - r_0^2+R^2}$. This is how integration then looks like
$$\int_B^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{R_g}^{r_0\sin\theta + \sqrt{(r_0\sin\theta)^2 - r_0^2+R^2}} r\arcsin{\left(\frac{R_{\rm g}}{r}\right)} {\rm d}r {\rm d}\theta$$
where $B= \arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{R^2 - A^2}+r_0}{A}\right)}$
My numerical integration is showing complex values, so I don't know where am I going wrong.

This is going to be a colossal mess in polar coordinates, as well. Substitute $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ into $y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and $y=\sqrt{R_g^2-x^2}+r_0$ and solve for $r$ as a function of $\theta$. Yuck. And when you plug those into the result of  $\int\arcsin(R_g/r)r,dr$, even yuckier.

What is your answer and how did you reach there? Edit your question to add that so we can help you find where exactly your mistake is.

Is your value of $A$ less than both $R$ and $R_g$

Since geometry is so often a guide to solving algebra/calculus problems, I was messing around with a visualization of the integrand function on your domain of integration here. You can drag the blue point $(X, Y)$ around and by construction of the yellow triangle, the corresponding angle $\theta$ at the origin satisfies $\sin\theta = R_{\mathrm{g}}/r$. As you can see, in polar coordinates the bounds are not pretty.
